# SSRS Report - Removing right side white space

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm developing an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2012. The report is set up to use landscape orientation. There is a 0.25in margin on the left and no margin on the right. The report is 10.5 inches wide. ConsumeContainerWhitespace is set to True. There are no hidden objects outside of the normal report area.

When I look at the report in print view or actually print it out there is a huge amount of white space on the right side of the report. It's almost like the report is being shrunk and then left justified when printing.

I would love to get this fixed so the report prints the same as it looks in the designer. If anyone has an opinion or some input it would be most welcome. Thank you!

[image: Print layout]
[image: Designer View]
[image: Report properties]

Comment: Just an update. This issue occurs within Visual Studio and in the built and deployed application in Windows 10. If I run the deployed application in Windows 7 there is no white space on the right side of the report. Taking a look at versions of Report Viewer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears when a Windows 10 user has their DPI set to a value that is higher than %100. If DPI is set to %100 then the issue does not occur and no white space is seen when doing a print view or actually printing the report.

This is a common issue with Windows 10 and certain applications including ClickOnce apps like the one I'm using to run the reports. There does not seem to be a way to fix this from within Visual Studio as you can't make an application DPI aware that uses the ClickOnce deployment model.

The following steps will fix a Report temporarily until it is updated and the .exe is overwritten. This fix will also work for other Windows 10 apps, including Chrome, that appear blurry from using a custom DPI over %100. Be aware though that while this fix will fix blurry fonts in a ClickOnce app and white space in an SSRS report it can also disturb control positioning and form size.

1. Navigate to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
2. Under the 2.0 directory you will see one or more folders that are named with a random set of letters and numbers. Within these directories you must find the folder for the desired application. The folders will usually start with the first 3 or four letters of the application but there can be more than one folder that exists for your application.
3. Locate the .exe for your application. There may be more than one .exe for your app so apply this fix fix to all of them just to be sure.
4. Rightclick on the .exe and select properties and click the Compatibility tab.
5. Check the Disable display scaling on high DPI settings checkbox and click OK
6. Rerun your application and create a report that opens the report viewer.
7. Click the Print Layout button. The report should now be displayed with no white space on the right.
8. Print the report. There should be no extra white space on the right side of the report.

You can also work around the issue by temporarily setting your DPI back to %100 but I think that is a poor solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matrix report, you may also try setting the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true.  It is Report level property that you can find under "Other".

or else if it is a tabular report then adjust the margin and width accordingly.

Here the link of the answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4a965d5c-0906-4690-a995-35aae594018c/how-to-avoid-empty-space-in-right-side-of-the-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you for the information. Those options will not resolve my particular issue but could certainly help another user who is no dealing with DPI scaling. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have me stumped but things I would check:

- There isn't a textbox or label or something pushing past the boundary of the expected margin.  This causes the report to print like what you are seeing.  Just expand the report and make sure everything is actually less than 10.25 inches.
- Is your paper size set to letter?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at my issue. Most appreciated. There is nothing outside of the report area and nothing goes past 10.5 inches. Even if it did to me that would extend the report right off the page not show the entire thing but smaller and left justified. Paper is set to letter.